# Ionic Geolocation

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic4

I am attempting to write an app that uses geolocation to get the user's position when they open up the app. I read that the geolocation services used by the phone and computer are the same, so testing geolocation on the computer is viable.

I have this block of code:

```
getPosition() {
        console.log("Getting Position");
        this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
            console.log("position = ");
            this.lat = resp.coords.latitude;
            this.long = resp.coords.longitude;
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error getting position");
            this.testVar = 10;
        });
        console.log("After position block");
        let watchT = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
        watchT.subscribe((data) => {
            //this.latitude = data.coords.latitude;
            //this.longitude = data.coords.longitude;
        });
    }
```

And when I run it in the browser and check the console, "Getting position" and "After position block" both print, but neither do "position = " or "Error getting position" print. I figured one of those would have to print based on whether it succeeded or failed.

What am I doing wrong here? Am I wrong in assuming I can test the geolocation on the computer?

Comment: Is `geolocation` a Cordova plugin?

Comment: Try adding  `let options =  {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
}` to your geolocation. e.g: `this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then()....`